# Como saber se a lista contém tanto elementos que atendam e que não atendam uma condição, usando stream?

Tags: java, java-8, revisão-de-código

Tenho uma lista de colunas, preciso saber se essa lista contém tanto colunas que são chaves como colunas que não são chaves.

> Eu garanto a existência de pelo menos uma coluna na lista

A minha classe de coluna:

```
public class Coluna {
  public boolean chave;
  public boolean isChave() { return chave; }
}
```

Minha verificação está assim no momento:

```
List<Coluna> minhasColunas = ...;
Predicate<Coluna> ehChave = Coluna::isChave;
boolean possuiColunasMistas =
    minhasColunas.stream().anyMatch(ehChave) &&
    minhasColunas.stream().anyMatch(ehChave.negate());
```

Existe alguma maneira mais idiomática de se fazer essa verificação? Achei muito estranho passar por duas *streams* para obter o resultado.

Numa verificação mais imperativa, eu faria o seguinte:

```
List<Coluna> minhasColunas = ...;
boolean achouChave = false;
boolean achouNaoChave = false;
for (Coluna c: minhasColunas) {
  if (c.chave) {
    achouChave = true;
    if (achouNaoChave) {
      break;
    }
  } else {
    achouNaoChave = true;
    if (achouChave) {
      break;
    }
  }
}

boolean possuiColunasMistas = achouChave && achouNaoChave;
```

Após a criação da questão, e conversa com o [@Anderson Carlos Woss](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5878/anderson-carlos-woss), acabei criando alguns cenários de teste para essa pergunta. Eles estão disponíveis aqui: https://gitlab.com/snippets/1724680

Então, se quiser validar sua própria resposta, implemente o método `boolean possuiColunasMistas(List<Coluna> colunas)` e depois é só rodar com o JUnit os casos de teste.

Comment: É necessário usar stream ou uma resposta iterando um for é válida ?

Comment: @ViníciusFerreira meu objetivo final é elegância. Nessa questão, foi realmente como usar `stream`, pressentia que tinha algo errado. Então, respostas elegantes são apreciadas, mesmo não sendo o foco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma lógica um pouco mais simples seria pegar o valor do primeiro elemento da lista e apenas verificar se há algum diferente deste na mesma. Se a lista for homogênea, todos os valores serão iguais e, portanto, não encontrará um valor diferente.

Acredito que ficaria próximo à:

```
boolean primeiraChave = lista.get(0).isChave();
boolean possuiColunasMistas = lista.stream().skip(1).anyMatch(it -> it.isChave() != primeiraChave)
```

Assim `possuiColunasMistas` será `true` apenas para listas heterogêneas.

> **Nota:** utilizar o `skip(1)` é opcional, visto que comparar o primeiro elemento com ele mesmo não alterará o resultado; mas também não faz sentido verificar se ele é diferente dele mesmo.